# If two fair dice are tossed, what is the probability that their sum is divisible by 5?

Tags: probability, contest-math

The answer for this question is $\frac{1}{4}$. I do not understand why.

This is my solution:
There can be only two possible ways to get a multiple of 5 with two dice rolls: 5 and 10.
In order to get 5, the first and second rolls must be 1 and 4, 2 and 3, 3 and 2, 4 and 1.
In order to get 10, the first and second rolls must be 6 and 4, 5 and 5, 4 and 6.

This means that the probability is a different fraction, $\frac{7}{36}$. How come the answer is $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: I think the given answer is wrong.

Comment: The given answer is correct if the sum were supposed to be divisible by $4$...  Any chance there's a typo'?

Comment: @EricTowers it's most likely a typo on the test-giver's part.